# PDO second fetchall() returns empty array

Tags: mysql, pdo

I try to execute multiple queries in one php file.
The first query works fine, but the second en third one return an empty array.

```
$DB_con = new PDO($dsn, $DB_user, $DB_pass, array(
PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));

$sql_sel_sponsoring = $DB_con->prepare('CALL SP_SELECT_SPONSORING(:id)');
$sql_sel_sponsoring->execute(array(':id' => $sponsor));
$sql_res_sponsoring = $sql_sel_sponsoring->fetchAll();

$sql_sel_sponsoring_type = $DB_con->prepare('CALL SP_SELECT_SPONSORING_TYPE()');
$sql_sel_sponsoring_type->execute();
$sql_res_sponsoring_type = $sql_sel_sponsoring_type->fetchAll();

$sql_sel_cbo_members = $DB_con->prepare('CALL SP_SELECT_CBO_MEMBERS()');
$sql_sel_cbo_members->execute();
$sql_res_cbo_members = $sql_sel_cbo_members->fetchAll();
```

With a vardump() I have different objects

```
var_dump($sql_sel_sponsoring);

var_dump($sql_sel_sponsoring_type);

var_dump($sql_sel_cbo_members);
```

Results

> object(PDOStatement)#6 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(30) "CALL SP_SELECT_SPONSORING(:id)" }
>
> object(PDOStatement)#7 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(32) "CALL SP_SELECT_SPONSORING_TYPE()" }
>
> object(PDOStatement)#8 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(28) "CALL SP_SELECT_CBO_MEMBERS()" }

But 2 of the 3 resultsets are empty

```
print_r($sql_res_sponsoring);

print_r($sql_res_sponsoring_type);

print_r($sql_res_cbo_members);
```

Giving:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [SID_SPONSORING] => 70 [0] => 70 [SID_SPONSOR] => 88 [1] => 88 [Jaar] => 2014 [2] => 2014 [Bedrag] => 60.00 [3] => 60.00 [Omschrijving] => Publiciteitsboekje heel A5 [4] => Publiciteitsboekje heel A5 ) )
> Array ( )
> Array ( )

How can I make it work?

Comment: Error handling?...if it's not there now . What are you going to do when it's in production and not working

Comment: You sure `CALL SP_SELECT_SPONSORING_TYPE()` is returning data?

Comment: Yes, all three procedures return data when I execute them in MySQL.